# How do you automate azure login with runbooks?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I want to run a script in powershell azure and when it runs I need it to connect automatically to Azure without prompting for specific user login and password details. I have automation accounts set up , can somebody advise the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create azure automation connection or use variable to pass in username\password combination. after that just use regular login with silent auth. Example of using azure automation connection

```
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "name goes here"
Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId | Out-Null
```

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-connections

Azure powershell silent auth can be done the same way, or just using Azure AD User:

```
$cred = [pscredential]::new('user',(ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password' -AsPlainText -Force))
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Many Thanks with regards to the Get-AutomationConnection -Name is the -Name a descriptive name , where does it get this from?

Comment: I ran the above but get Get-AutomationConnection : Connections asset not found. To create this Connections asset, navigate to the Assets blade 
and create a Connections asset named: Test

Comment: how does rbac solve this issue? first option allows you to not put credentials in the code. @Rthomas529

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment, you are using RBAC when you using service principle.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account